# Expression for "medium difficult"?

Tags: phrases, idioms, expressions, phrase-requests

In my game, I have three levels of difficulty, each represented by an icon. Of course, each level is also indicated by a word; the icons are there just to spice things up, and as a visual pun.

- **Easy** is represented by a "piece of cake".
- **Medium** is represented by ...?
- **Hard** is represented by a "tough nut".

So, what could be used for the medium difficulty level?

Comment: Lots of things come to mind. I think this question would benefit from having a single community-edited answer.

Comment: @RegDwight: If lots of things come to mind, please post them! :)

Comment: I would, but right now I'm contemplating whether this might be a better fit for the [Game Development](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) StackExchange.

Comment: I don't think so. The fact that it's for a game is secondary; I'm looking for English expressions and idioms here.

Comment: @RegDwight: Regarding CW status, what is different between this and all other “what is is called” questions? I believe CW isn't used as much as it was in the past, and I don't think it's warranted here.

Comment: @FX_: I'm not saying that the *question* should be necessarily CW. I'm just saying that the best *answer* might be a community-edited one. Kind of like here: [List of Simple Word From English Alphabets A-Z for Children Book Illustration](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6990/).

Comment: Is this question about English language?

Comment: @kiamlaluno: yes, it's about visual interpretation of an English word. I think that falls under usage.

Comment: @Matt Ellen: To me it sounds like asking for the English interpretation of a picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A steak? Cooked Medium, of course.

Comment: Mmm, good one, I like it!

Comment: You could extend this visual metaphor to your other difficulties if you wished, from Rare (easy) to Well Done (tough).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a crystal ball?  (Used by a "Medium")  :-)

Answer (score 0):

What about "**Bittersweet Salad**"?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the word-

> **Springboard** or **Trampoline**

as it is the first word that came to my mind

Comment: Doesn't answer the question, per se, but a good point nonetheless. I think "intermediate" is better.

Comment: oh, sorry, I read the question halfway and was in the edit phase as you were commenting. :)